# Passing a delegate as a type parameter and using it throws error CS0314

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, delegates

I'm trying to pass a delegate type as a type parameter so that I can then use it as a type parameter later on in the code, like so:

```
// Definition
private static class Register
{
  public static FunctionObject Create<T>(CSharp.Context c, T func)
  {
    return new IronJS.HostFunction<T>(c.Environment, func, null);
  }
}

// Usage
Register.Create<Func<string, IronJS.CommonObject>>(c, this.Require);
```

However, the C# compiler complains:

```
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'a' in the generic type or method
'IronJS.HostFunction<a>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter
conversion from 'T' to 'System.Delegate'."
```

I attempted to fix this by appending "where T : System.Delegate" to the function, however, you can't use System.Delegate as a restriction on type parameters:

```
Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Delegate'
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this conflict?

**DOESN'T WORK (Argument and return type information is lost during cast):**

```
Delegate d = (Delegate)(object)(T)func;
return new IronJS.HostFunction<Delegate>(c.Environment, d, null);
```

Comment: Why does your solution contain a `(T)`?

Comment: @Gabe: It was the type that is passed in Create<T>.  Unfortunately the proposed solution doesn't work at runtime.

Comment: Can you show the code for the proposed solution that doesn't work and explain how it doesn't work?

Comment: @Gabe: I added it back to the post.

Comment: I don't understand how casting an object can lose information. What does "Argument and return type information is lost during cast" mean? How do you know? Do you get an actual error message?

Comment: When IronJS goes to retrieve the argument and parameter information for the delegate, it can no longer find it (due to the cast or the fact that HostFunction has Delegate as the type parameter instead of the actual delegate).

Comment: OK, the problem is `HostFunction<Delegate>`, not the cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at https://github.com/fholm/IronJS/blob/master/Src/IronJS/Runtime.fs you'll see:

```ml
and [<AllowNullLiteral>] HostFunction<'a when 'a :> Delegate> =
  inherit FO
  val mutable Delegate : 'a

  new (env:Env, delegateFunction, metaData) =
  {
      inherit FO(env, metaData, env.Maps.Function)
      Delegate = delegateFunction
  }
```

In other words, you cannot use C# or VB to write your function because it requires using `System.Delegate` as a type constraint. I recommend either writing your function in F# or using reflection, like this:

```
public static FunctionObject Create<T>(CSharp.Context c, T func)
{
  // return new IronJS.HostFunction<T>(c.Environment, func, null);
  return (FunctionObject) Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(IronJS.Api.HostFunction<>).MakeGenericType(T),
    c.Environment, func, null);
}
```

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance<IronJS.Api.HostFunction<T>>(c.Environment, func, null);` should work too, no? Also, good catch on the F# constraint :)

Comment: @leppie: The same thing that prevents `new` from working will also prevent `Activator.CreateInstance` from working.

Answer (score 1):

@Gabe is completely right, it has to do with the type constraint on the HostFunction<'a> class that is only valid in F# (and not C# or VB).

Have you checked the functions in [Native.Utils](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS/blob/master/Src/IronJS/Native.Utils.fs)? It's what we use internally in the runtime to create functions from delegates. Especially the `let CreateFunction (env:Env) (length:Nullable<int>) (func:'a when 'a :> Delegate) =` function should do exactly what you need.

If CreateFunction doesn't fulfill what you need, open a ticket at http://github.com/fholm/IronJS/issues with what you're missing and how you'd like to see it implemented and we'll get right on it.

Comment: It's not only valid in F#.  It's valid in any .NET language that hasn't intentionally <strike>crippled</strike> restricted type constraints.

Answer (score 0):

**As an update to anyone reading this after May 2018:**

As of c# 7.3 (.Net Framework 4.7.2), it *is* now possible to use `where T : System.Delegate` as a constraint on a generic declaration, which means that the original poster would now be able to do what she was trying to do in c# - without having to resort to building the class with another .Net language.

`System.Enum` (another sorely-missed constraint in earlier versions of c#) is now available too. There are a couple of other additions as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#delegate-constraints